# auto fill of two adjacent cells in excel

Tags: excel

I want to use the auto fill but with two adjacent cells which contain different values as in the following
[Image #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHM1Y.png)

I want to fill cells from E1 to H1 with the following values

[Image #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0pttO.png)

I don't want to use VBA. Just auto fill method

Answer (score 0):

How much do you want to autofill? Kind of a roundabout way, but could you start auto filling just letters a, b, c.... as far as you need down col A, then numbers 1, 2, 3.... at bottom of your letter range. Then 1, 2, 3, down col B to end of letters then start at 1 again. Then sort by col B ascending, col A desending should give you the alternating sequence. Finally copy, paste special.... transpose to get across the way.

Comment: I don't understand "then start at 1 again", So Col B will contain 1,2,3, ... and what?

Comment: Col B = 1, 2, 3......, 1, 2, 3...... It is used purely for sorting col A in correct order.